# Accordion-toggle not working on IE 11 (bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below Pasted Code is working great on Chrome and Firefox but latest IE versions are not showing accordion-toggle collapse.

Chrome and FF Screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCdx1TYINUsQjIwdnlhVDN5eGM/view?usp=sharing

How it appears on IE:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCdx1TYINUsajE5eExicmlaejg/view?usp=sharing

```
               <div class="panel-collapse" collapse="!client.isDaySelected">
            <div class="panel-body container-fluid">

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" >
                        <div class="panel-heading">Select Goal/Allowable services for Data Collection</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" ng-click="">Absences</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" ng-click="hospitialization()">Hospitialization</button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div style="overflow-x:scroll;width:100%;">
                            <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        --table headers
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody ng-repeat="service in serviceDetails">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tr_{{service.ResHabOutId}}" class="accordion-toggle btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                                        </td>
                                        -- some more tds

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                                            <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="tr_{{service.ResHabOutId}}" ng-if="service.lstDataCollectionSummary.length">
                                                <table class="table table-striped" style="outline: 1px solid black;">
                                                    <thead>
                                                      --some rows
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                       --some rows
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you notice I have ng-repeat on tbody ( for Simplicity) because I want to display data on per goal basis.

If needed I can paste in the links and js references for your review.
Any help ?

Comment: does the DOM look good? do oyu get any console errors?

Comment: DOM looks good except few errors from fastclick.js

Comment: well... fix the errors?

Comment: Removed fast click reference..still no help..

Comment: if the DOM looks fine it's probably a styling issue